# Server Application Error

Tags: asp.net

The server has encountered an error while loading an application during the processing of your request. Please refer to the event log for more detail information. Please contact the server administrator for assistance

Comment: You really need to give more than that

Answer (score 4):

This one's pretty easy to fix.

The server encountered an error while loading an application during the processing of your request.

You should refer to the event log for more detailed information.

If you need any additional assistance, contact your server administrator.